# Run windows service automatically forever, after starting manually for the first time

Tags: c#, windows-services

I created a Windows service application. It runs depending on the app settings which is included in the app.config file. It will be installed on different locations (networks, PCs) at the same time. Each location will need to set its own parameters in the app.config file. So I don't want it to run automatically after installation. By doing that each location users will be able to open configuration file and change it. Then they can start the service. But after that the service will run forever. Even when they restart the windows, it will run automatically after Windows opened.

Here is my installer class. It doesn't run automatically after installation. That's good. But if I run it manually and restart PC, when restart complete, it still waits to be started manually. What should I do?

```
public partial class MyServiceInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    ServiceInstaller _serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
    ServiceProcessInstaller _processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
    string _serviceName = "MyService";
    string _displayName = "My Service";
    string _description = "My Service - Windows Service";

    public MyServiceInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.BeforeInstall += new InstallEventHandler(MyServiceInstaller_BeforeInstall);

        _processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

        _serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
        _serviceInstaller.Description = _description;
        _serviceInstaller.ServiceName = _serviceName;
        _serviceInstaller.DisplayName = _displayName;

        Installers.Add(_serviceInstaller);
        Installers.Add(_processInstaller);
    }

    protected override void OnCommitted(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
    {
        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(_serviceName);

        if (sc.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
        {
            TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000);
            sc.Start();
            sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
            sc.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            RestartService(10000);
        }
    }

    private void RestartService(int timeoutMiliseconds)
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(_serviceName);

        int millisec1 = Environment.TickCount;
        TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMiliseconds);

        service.Stop();
        service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

        int millisec2 = Environment.TickCount;
        timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMiliseconds - (millisec2 - millisec1));

        service.Start();
        service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
    }

    void MyServiceInstaller_BeforeInstall(object sender, System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        List<ServiceController> services = new List<ServiceController>(ServiceController.GetServices());

        foreach (ServiceController s in services)
        {
            if (s.ServiceName == this._serviceInstaller.ServiceName)
            {
                ServiceInstaller ServiceInstallerObj = new ServiceInstaller();
                ServiceInstallerObj.Context = new System.Configuration.Install.InstallContext();
                ServiceInstallerObj.Context = Context;
                ServiceInstallerObj.ServiceName = _serviceName;
                ServiceInstallerObj.Uninstall(null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be setting the startup type to Automatic. Can you check the event log to see if your service is attempting to start automatically, but failing. This can happen if your service depends on another service which has not yet started.

Comment: @sgmoore thanks for your comment. I realised that my code depends on some other code which needs to wait some time before being executed after reboot. Write this as an answer please and I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code already seems to be setting the startup type to Automatic.

Can you check the event log to see if your service is attempting to start automatically, but failing. This can happen if your service depends on another service which has not yet started.

Comment: Thanks, it was failing because of the dependencies. It should wait some time after reboot to execute successfully. So setting DelayedAutoStart value of the installer to true solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this easier for yourself, by downloading the NuGet Package called [TopShelf](https://topshelf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

To summarize briefly, quoting from their [page](https://topshelf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview/index.html):

> Topshelf is a framework for hosting services written using the .NET
>   framework. The creation of services is simplified, allowing developers
>   to create a simple console application that can be installed as a
>   service using Topshelf. The reason for this is simple: It is far
>   easier to debug a console application than a service. And once the
>   application is tested and ready for production, Topshelf makes it easy
>   to install the application as a service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sc config](https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/cc990290%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) after service start to modify start type.

eg.

```
sc config yourservicename start=auto
```

Or you can use [ChangeServiceConfig](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681987(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but its start type already seems to be Automatic after the installation finishes. So, no need to change it. Also the users will never run any cmd command.

Comment: @OrkunBekar if start type is automatic then after Windows restart service must start but meybe it fails for some reason, look at EventLog for service errors.

Comment: @orkunbekar if the start type is set to automatic, it will automatically start on reboot. But setting the start type to auto does not mean "start immediately". You have to do the initial start manually. Also, it does not mean "restart after it stopped/crashed" there are separate settings for that.

Comment: @BWA I looked at the events but couldnt find useful information thanks.

Comment: @derpirscher thanks for that information. Then I must write an algorithm in oncommitted to stop at first time, then after second run it won't call sc.stop again. Right?

Comment: @OrkunBekar add loging to service, you can see how it works or where is problem